# Graphviz Record-like Structure with XY-Pic or Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xy-pic

I sketched the following graph with Graphviz, but I don’t know how to do it with XY-Pic or Tikz. The thing here is that I used record style node. Is there a way to do it with the other two?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it in Ti*k*Z, but `forest` package could be more acurate.

Comment: @SebGlav This graph is quite simple, but I have other ones that are not trees at all. The real need is that I can use both cells as target for arrows.

Comment: So you need to be more specific about what you really want. If your issue is for the two parts boxes, then you'll have to check `multipart nodes` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example, using `forest` package. It's not the best fit you can achieve with it but it works.

[image: graphviz]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows.meta}

\forestset{rect/.style = {rectangle split,
                        rectangle split parts=2,
                        draw}
          }
          
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={edge={-Latex},child anchor=north,l=15mm}
        [Methane,draw
            [s1\nodepart{two}Carbon,rect]
            [s2\nodepart{two}Hydrogen,rect]
            [s3\nodepart{two}Hydrogen,rect]
            [s4\nodepart{two}Hydrogen,rect]
            [s5\nodepart{two}Hydrogen,rect]
        ]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can do it in plain Ti*k*Z, including the `multiparts` option, like the following:

[image: V2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{r/.style = {
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=2,
            draw,
            inner sep=5pt,
            align=center
                    }
          }
          
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
        \node[draw,minimum height=1cm](M){Methane};
        \node[below=of M,r](3){s3\nodepart{two}\strut Hydrogen};
        \node[left=of 3,r](2){s2\nodepart{two}\strut Hydrogen};
        \node[left=of 2,r](1){s1\nodepart{two}\strut Carbon};
        \node[right=of 3,r](4){s4\nodepart{two}\strut Hydrogen};
        \node[right=of 4,r](5){s5\nodepart{two}\strut Hydrogen};
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \draw[->] (M) -- (\i.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, and very simple. A suggestion though: for a slightly better (vertical) fit you can put a `\strut` before Carbon and Hydrogen.

Comment: I was posting an edit with `strut` actually.